# Mysql connection refuse in docker

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose, symfony4

So i am creating a new symfony 4 project but i cant get mysql to connect to my docker mysql.   what part am i doing wrong?

Ive tried change mysql versions, composing it down and updating different mysql root and password and is not connecting.

here is my docker-compose.yml for mysql.

```
mysql:
        image: mysql:8
        container_name: sf4_mysql
        volumes:
            - .docker/data/db:/var/lib/mysql
        command:
            - "--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"
            - "--lower_case_table_names=1"        
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: sf4
            MYSQL_USER: sf4
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: sf4
```

Here is mysql Url in my .env 
    DATABASE_URL=mysql://sf4:sf4@sf4_mysql:3306/sf4

every-time i do ./bin/console doctrine:database:create, connection is refused.

just trying to create a database.

controller

```
class HospitalAdminController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/admin/hospital/new")
     */
    public function new(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $hospital = new Hospital();
        $hospital->setName('Example Hospital')
            ->setPhone(8175831483)
            ->setAddress('123 Avenue');

        $em->persist($hospital);
        $em->flush();


        return new Response(sprintf(
            'Hiya! New Hospital id: #%d phone:%s address%s',
            $hospital->getId(),
            $hospital->getPhone(),
            $hospital->getAddress()

        ));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expose mysql port. default is 3306.
see [port publishing](https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/docker-cloud/apps/ports/#launch-a-service-with-a-published-port)

and more examples specific to [mysql-8 on docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql)

For checking if mysql is running it is good to run inside terminal its client so you minimize potential error source to the database itself not including potential errors in php.

Comment: do you know why when i flush the connection refuses? @Jimmix

Comment: @Chris2kus what do you exactly mean by flush?

Comment: I am trying to call this (i updated my original post to show my controller.  I am getting an error 

An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

@Jimmix

Comment: check if you really use admin/root user or the other user you use is allowed to create db at MySQL. The other thing is to create second container with mysql client and try to create any db by using console. If it goes well in mysql console you know the problem is in php. if not there is something not right with mysql.

Comment: I was able to create a database with the root user, after I ran ./bin/console doctrine:database:create, it created the database.  however, when i am trying write, it refuse the connection with the same settings @Jimmix

Comment: @Chris2kus unlucky I can't help you. Post it as new question, perfectly with configuration you use and error message you get.